# Facebook Scraper: COULDNT_CONNECT to fwdproxy port 8082

Tags: apache, facebook, curl, facebook-debugger, mod-evasive

Im surprised to see Facebook did not scrape my website for a while and debugging shows an error

```
COULDNT_CONNECT Failed to connect to fwdproxy port 8082: Connection refused
```

Why all of sudden Facebook scraper changed their request to port 8082 ? Or is that normal ?

The port 8082 was never open and all those 6 months fb scraped without any issues and while I was trying to find out what happened this time, that issue resolved automatically. I guess fb  changed reqest to 80 or 443

Any idea please ?

Comment: I don’t think that message has anything to do with what ports Facebook makes its requests from. (Every normal browser accessing your site uses an arbitrary port (> 1024 or sth.) _on their end_ to do so, 80/443 are the standard ports on the _receiving_ end, your server.) This sounds like your setup has some sort of proxy server in front of the actual web server, and that proxy server refused the connection.

Comment: @04FS,  Apache evasive module was enabled and since it is a news portal parameters were configured to a high value DOSPageCount=75, DOSSiteCount=200 for interval 1s and the block period was 20 seconds. There was no other server/application changes. And when noticed the scrapper issue, I Completely disabled the module and Apache was restarted. Still fb coudn't  complete a successful scrap request. If it was Evasive block, is it  possible to exist   even after module was disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Facebook Platform Status](https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/2298401886902830/), there is a Disruption across Platform & APIs on 6th Jun which webhooks are affected. I encountered this issue last week with the same error message. It should be resolved now.

[image]